# ActivityNotFoundException with document.location.href on a plugin callback

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

My problem is quite hard to explain clearly...

I call a phonegap plugin to download and unzip a zip, and on the callback i return the url of the new page to load the new page :

bindings.js (Where the binding is done) :

```
showGameDetailComplete: function(data) {
    [...]
    $('#play-game').bind('tap',function() {
        var gameDownloader = new GameDownloader();
        gameDownloader.downloadGame(data.url, data.id, 
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
                document.location.href = data;
            }, function(data) {
                alert('Download failed');
            }
        );
    })
},
```

gamedownloader.js (The link between JS - Android) :

```
GameDownloader.prototype.downloadGame = function(fileUrl, gameId,
     successCallback, failureCallback) {
PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, "GameDownloader", "download", [ fileUrl, gameId]);
};
```

GameDownloaderPlugin.java (The Phonegap Android native plugin) :

```
public class GameDownloaderPlugin extends Plugin
{
[...]

@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId)
{
    result = null;
    mCallbackId = callbackId;
    if (action.equals(ACTION_DOWNLOAD))
    {
        try
        {
            downloadGame(data.getString(0), data.getString(1));
            result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            return result;
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Param errors");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        Log.d("DirectoryListPlugin", "Invalid action : " + action + " passed");
    }
    return result;
}

private void downloadGame(String fileUrl, String gameId)
{
    try
    {
        /* Downloading the zip */
        [...]

        /* Unzip the zip */
        Intent iUnzip = new Intent(ctx, GameUnzipActivity.class);
        iUnzip.putExtra(UNZIP_GAMEID, gameId);
        iUnzip.putExtra(UNZIP_SRCFILE, fileName);
        ctx.startActivityForResult(this, iUnzip, GAME_UNZIP);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (LOG)
            Log.d("GameDownloaderPlugin", "Error: " + e);
        this.error(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Error: " + e), mCallbackId);
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case (GAME_UNZIP):
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                if (LOG)
                    Log.d("GameDownloaderPlugin", "Game unzipped! \\o/");
                this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "../../games/" + mGameId + "/"), this.mCallbackId);
            }
            else
            {
                if (LOG)
                    Log.d("GameDownloaderPlugin", "Bide!");
                this.error(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR), this.mCallbackId);
            }               
        }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

So here the unzip activity is called, then return a result in onActivityResult() :

```
PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "../../games/" + mGameId + "/"), this.mCallbackId);
```

Here... No problem, the game is well unzipped, the callback is well sent, received in bindings.js :

```
function(data) {
                alert(data);
                document.location.href = data + 'html/fr/index.html';
}
```

The alert(data) show the good callback, but the document.location.href line logcat an error :

```
Error loading url content://com.tuto.android.provider.DataFileProvider/games/1/html/fr/index.html
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.tuto.android.provider.DataFileProvider/games/1/html/fr/index.html }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
at com.phonegap.DroidGap.startActivityForResult(DroidGap.java:1523)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
at com.phonegap.DroidGap$GapViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(DroidGap.java:1338)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:216)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:323)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And for information, I use a provider to show my pages included in the /data/data/*package*/files file, that's why I have this URL :

```
content://com.tuto.android.provider.DataFileProvider/games/1/html/fr/index.html
```

If you want more explication tell me more, it's quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I've finally found a solution :

When I want a new page to be shown, I use a new plugin for starting the principal activity DroidGap a second time with the url parameter :

```
public class MyActivity extends DroidGap
{
  [...]

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();

    if (b == null)
    {
        super.loadUrl(PROV_WWW + "html/fr/index.html");
    }
    else
    {
        String url = b.getString("URL");

        super.loadUrl(url);
    }
  }
}
```

It's more a workaround than a real solution, but it's actually working.